# Ordenar lista alfabeticamente en Python

Tags: python, lista, ordenar

Tengo entendido que con el metodo sort() puedo ordenar alfabeticamente una lista.

```
names = ['Gato', 'Perro', 'Caballo', 'Cerdo', 'Conejo']
names.sort()
print (names)

# ['Caballo', 'Cerdo', 'Conejo', 'Gato', 'Perro']
```

Todo bien hasta aqui. Es ordenada correctamente. Pero cuando quiero hacerlo desde una funcion, me retorna "None".

```
names = ['Gato', 'Perro', 'Caballo', 'Cerdo', 'Conejo']

def sort_names(names):
   return names.sort()

print (sort_names(names))
# None
```

Hice pruebas con el return, indentado y devuelve otros elementos correctamente, al igual que el sort funciona bien fuera de la funcion. ¿Donde esta mi error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `sort()` de la clase `list` realiza un ordenamiento *in-place*, como bien menciona [la documentación](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list.sort). O sea, modifica el objeto a través del cual es llamado el método. Además, devuelve `None`.

Lo que quieres es utilizar la *builtin* function `sorted()` la cual está basada en [el mismo método de ordenamiento](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) que `list.sort()`, pero devuelve una nueva lista con los elementos ordenados.

Te quedaría:

```
def sort_names(names):
   return sorted(names)
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no tienes error, simplementa quita del print el sort_name, pues al retornarlo y tambien invocarlo en el print estas haciendo una redundancia.

```
def sort_names(names):
       return names.sort()

print (names)
```